# && return 1 not terminating script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to exit my script when the user presses enter when prompted for the department number. However for some reason it's not exiting and I'm not sure why? I've been banging my head trying to figure this out! Thanks for the help. Here is the code:

```
checkDeptNum()
{

    local input

    while : ; do
        read -p "Enter department number (Press ENTER to quit):" input
        [ -z "$input" ] && return 1 #This is the line thats not working
        while read line; do
                if cut -d: -f3 "$file" | grep -w "$input"; then
                        break
                else
                        r=$input
                        return 0
                fi
        done < Managers

        error "Department number '$input' already exists in the file"
    done
}

while : ; do
checkDeptNum
    if [ -n "$r" ]; then
        read -p "Enter the department name:" deptName
        read -p "Enter the manager's name:" manName
        read -p "Enter the manager's ID#:" manID
        echo "$manName:$manID:$r:$deptName" >> "$file"
   fi
done
```

Comment: No `break` in second (main) `while` loop ?

Comment: What do you see when you run the script with `set -x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to use `exit 1` instead of `return 1` and `exit 0` instead of `return 0`

Your return is written in a function, so it can't complete anything other than your function.

Comment: It's nice to downvote, but it would be better to justify your opinion.

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted :( But changing it to exit 1 fixed my issue so upvote and accepted! Thanks!!

Comment: I would say it was not worth a downvote, but the downvoter may have thought it better to continue using `return` inside the function, and call it using `checkDeptNum || exit` instead. Generally, it's better to let the caller of a function to decide whether to exit the script than to have the function do it.